# Thread secundaria no flutter

Tags: mobile, thread, flutter, multithreading, dart

Olá, estou com o seguinte problema no flutter: atualmente tenho um aplicativo com o plugin [flutter_background_geolocation](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation) baseado no exemplo que é fornecido pelo plugin. Ao realizar alguns testes e analisar os resultados o meu professor requisitou que eu disparasse duas threads com o plugin e implementasse no lado do servidor uma logica para ler apenas uma por vez(a segunda thread seria uma reserva para caso a primeira falha-se) a logica de envio e recebimento já foi implementada. A questão que me travou foi como implementar uma segunda thread no flutter com isso comecei a pesquisar e cheguei as seguintes perguntas:

1) O uso de promisses seria o bastante pra realizar essa ação? li que não são indicadas para coisas demoradas pois não são threads separadas e sim usam um sistema de [event loop](https://miro.medium.com/max/1030/0*9MGKEGhpQAYnl_HX.png) parecido com o do node.

2) Encontrei na documentação uma função chamada [compute](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html), porém fiquei em duvidas sobre a sua implementação e se ela me atenderia, todos os exemplos que vi dela realizavam ações curtas(poucos segundos) e preciso de algo que vai rodar indefinidamente.

3) Seria o uso de [platform channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) uma opção? creio q seja a opção mais complicada porém a mais robusta.

4) O uso de uma segunda thread em si é uma boa opção para garantir o envio dos dados? quais seriam outra possíveis soluções?

Comment: Faça uma analise dos possíveis problemas para ver se realmente é necessário o uso de duas _threads_... Duas _threads_ rodando, é 2x mais uso dos recursos, é 2x mais uso de processamento. Quais os motivos de uma delas falhar? Como garantir que se uma falhar, a outra também não irá falhar pelo mesmo motivo? Acho mais válido você fazer muito bem um controle em uma única _thread_ do que ter duas com o mesmo propósito.

Comment: Foi o que o professor responsável pelo projeto requisitou, eu já corrigi os erros que faziam falhar mas ele ainda acha necessário

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Programação assíncrona em Flutter é realizada através do [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html). Não entendi o porquê de usar dois `Future`. Se a ideia é que o segundo seja um backup em caso de erro, você pode usar a própria API do Future pra tratar os erros.

No exemplo abaixo, se vc comentar a linha `throw 'error';` ele imprime "Ok 1". Se deixar como está, vai imprimir "Ok 2".

```
 Future<String> primeiraChamada() async {
    throw 'error';
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1), () => 'ok 1');
  }
  
  Future<String> segundaChamada() async {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds:1), () => 'ok 2');
  }
  
  void fazerChamadaAPI(){
    primeiraChamada()
      .then((result) => print(result))
      .catchError((error) => segundaChamada()
             .then((result) => print(result))
             .catchError((error) => print(error))
      );
  }
  
  fazerChamadaAPI();
```

1. Sim. Você usa o tipo `Future` justamente para isso.
2. Não precisa. `compute` só é usado pra iniciar `isolates` e mesmo nesses casos tem formas melhores de fazer. https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html
3. `Platform Channels` não é para isso. São usados pra criar código nas SDKs nativas quando você não tem uma opção dentro do Flutter. Você pode usar para criar threads, mas fazer em Dart é bem mais fácil e com melhor desempenho.
4. Foi a primeira dúvida que eu tive ao ler a pergunta. A melhor forma é tratar a resposta da primeira chamada, ou o erro, e ver o que fazer a partir dali (criar outra chamada, agendar pra mandar depois, salvar local, etc)